# Widget custom icon Android

Tags: android, widget

I would like to make a custom image for a widget, i tried

```
views.setImageViewResource(R.id.red_button, R.drawable.button_default);
```

and

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
        R.drawable.button_default);

    views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.red_button, icon);
```

but it says problem loading widget all the time, no matter what I try, am I missing something? can someone point me to the right documantion/what to do?
Edit:
full xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/red_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Button"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/button_default" />

</LinearLayout>
```

code:

```
public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

        CharSequence widgetText = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text);
        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.red_button, pi);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.red_button, widgetText);

        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.button_default);

        views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.red_button, icon);
        //views.setImageViewResource(R.id.red_button, R.drawable.button_default);


        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide xml of remote view and app-widget-provider info?

Comment: I edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message ("problem loading widget") is not caused by any problems with displaying the drawable, it is showing because of this line in your code:

> `views.setTextViewText(R.id.red_button, widgetText);`

You can only use `setTextViewText(int, CharSequence)` with resource ids for `View`s extending from `TextView` (according to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews#setTextViewText(int,%20java.lang.CharSequence)), it's equivalent to `TextView.setText(CharSequence)` ).

The resource id `R.id.red_button` belongs to an `ImageButton` which extends from `ImageView` not from `TextView`, that's why you get the error message.

So if you want to show some text you need to add a `Textview` to your app widget's layout.